# Java JTabbedPane only see one tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I was making een tabbedpane but all the tabs are on top of each other or there is only on added. but i can't find a solution.

this is my code:

```
public Frame(int width, int height) {
    setSize(width, height);

    setTitle("NerdyGadgets backoffice");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("test the label");
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    tabbedPane.addTab("firstpane", label);
    tabbedPane.addTab("secondpane", label);
    tabbedPane.addTab("test", null, label, "test test test");

    add(tabbedPane);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

and this is the result that i get:
[https://gyazo.com/4027807aa305beb227ca4a402d43f067](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4BKA.png)

Comment: Don't re-use the label - it can only belong to a single parent container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component can only belong to a single parent, which means that in your case, it will only be applied to the last tab

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel("test the label");
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

tabbedPane.addTab("firstpane", new JLabel("Tab 1"));
tabbedPane.addTab("secondpane", new JLabel("Tab 2"));
tabbedPane.addTab("test", null, label, "test test test");

add(tabbedPane);
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't knew this